# How to use setfillstyle() and textcolor() in C

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses, conio

I want to use setfillstyle() and textcolor() in UBUNTU(terminal) .

But I found on internet that it is store in conio.h library which cannot be used in UBUNTU .

So what should I do ?

Comment: I removed your 2nd question about `inportb`. If you want to ask about that, ask a separate question. You should probably tell what you want to do, show how you would do it in MSDOS using `inportb`, and ask how to do it Ubuntu (because the way to do it will be totally different, or it may even be impossible without writing a kernel driver...).

Answer (score 1):

The de facto way to do these things on unixy terminals today is to use some [Curses libray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)), which on Ubuntu is [Ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) developed by GNU Project.

Google for "ncurses tutorial" to get started. It is different from *conio.h*, so just learn it from scratch.

Comment: in Curses what would be the function which is alternative for 'setfillstyle' and 'textcolor'

Comment: @Koolman I think it is `attron`. But the whole library is a bit different. Instead of thinking which function corresponds to which function, you're better off thinking in terms of "this is how I display something using conio.h, how do I achieve same display using ncruses?"

Answer (score 1):

That's true. `setfillstyle` and `textcolor` are functions of the old conio MS/DOS library. It can only be used nowadays in Windows consoles (unless you manage to use a real MS/DOS or FreeDOS...).

If you want to use color effect in a Linux terminal window, you could have a look at curses which normally exists in Ubuntu and allows to create portable programs.

Comment: in Curses what would be the function which is alternative for 'setfillstyle' and 'textcolor'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, controlling a "screen" (or however you want to call it) is **not** in the scope of C. C I/O (`stdio.h`) only operates on input and output streams. Therefore, you either have to write platform-specific code yourself or use a library.

About `conio.h`, as other answers already state, this is an obsolete header. It was created for MS-DOS (AFAIK by Borland for their TurboC product) and as a result is by design strongly coupled to what a typical PC in textmode with BIOS routines provides. Although you probably find **some** implementations of it for other systems than MS-DOS, I'd strongly recommend not to use it.

The **de facto** standard nowadays for controlling a console/terminal is indeed `curses`, which first emerged on Unix systems. It was part of a commercial system, but free implementations for a variety of systems exist. Using `curses`, your code will be portable to many systems, including virtually all *nix derivates as well as Windows.

Two implementations of `curses` are very widespread:

- [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) from the GNU project, this is portable to many *nix systems and more recently to windows as well (I'd recommend it for Linux, FreeBSD etc.)
- [pdcurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/) which is portable as well, but with a focus on DOS and Windows (I'd recommend it for Windows)

For learning how to use `curses`, the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) is a great resource. I personally recommend to `#include <curses.h>` everywhere this HOWTO suggests `#include <ncurses.h>`, so your code can be used with other curses implementations without modification.

Comment: in Curses what would be the function which is alternative for 'setfillstyle' and 'textcolor'

Comment: @Koolman there's no 1:1 mapping, you should really work through the HOWTO.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, *ncurses* is the usual place to start looking with Ubuntu.

According to [this page](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/graphics.h/setfillstyle)

> setfillstyle function sets the current fill pattern and fill color.

and goes on to list the available fill-styles:

```
enum fill_styles 
{ 
   EMPTY_FILL, 
   SOLID_FILL, 
   LINE_FILL, 
   LTSLASH_FILL, 
   SLASH_FILL,
   BKSLASH_FILL, 
   LTBKSLASH_FILL, 
   HATCH_FILL, 
   XHATCH_FILL, 
   INTERLEAVE_FILL,
   WIDE_DOT_FILL, 
   CLOSE_DOT_FILL, 
   USER_FILL 
};
```

There's no portable equivalent to the *fill pattern* (it's dependent upon the terminal type).  Depending on what you want, `<conio.h>` is used for coloring *full-screen* or *command-line* applications.  With the latter, you have [`tput`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) (a curses utility), which can set foreground and/or background colors.

For the former, *ncurses* implements the X/Open *background character*, which can be used in full-screen applications to provide a combination of a fill-character and/or color.  You could imitate *conio*'s fill-style using the *background character* (though I haven't seen anyone make a table of corresponding Unicode values for those).  `EMPTY_FILL` is easy: just a space character.

Further reading:

- [**`tput`**, **`reset`** - initialize a terminal or query terminfo database](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)
- [**`bkgrnd`**,  **`wbkgrnd`**, **`bkgrndset`**, **`wbkgrndset`**, **`getbkgrnd`**, **`wgetbkgrnd`** - curses window complex background manipulation routines](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgrnd.3x.html)
- [test/sample programs](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) (several use the background character)