# Getting the undefined reference error while using gotoxy() function in c in dev-cpp

Tags: linker-errors, undefined-reference, dev-c++

This is  the full error that I get when trying to compile:

> C:\Users\avrlsngh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGLqeDo.o   gotoxy.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `gotoxy'

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45812107/2371524) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926302/2371524) I wrote.

Comment: http://conio.sourceforge.net/ may be of interest.

Comment: Btw, this isn't a question. And if you make it to ask what this error means, there's a canonical duplicate ...

Comment: @IanAbbott I would strongly advice against that. It's only good for old code when porting it to `curses` would take too much time. For writing new code, never use `conio` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linker error.

`gotoxy()` is Turbo-C not C. So the function is simply not available with the environment, compiler, libraries you use.

The code uses a function (`gotoxy()` here) it does not define itself. So the compiler/linker tries to resolve it during linkage but cannot find it in any object file and/or library specified.